# Why is my bootstrap navbar breaking

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a navbar like below which has `300px` on left side and `300px` on right side with center `100%` width. How we can we achieve this layout using bootstrap navbar.

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|               |    Center 100% fluid width                       |             
|  SITE LOGO    |------------------------------------------- ----- | Right      +
|               |                                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

left fixed width —— middle fluid % —— right fixed width
```

Below is the `fiddle` on what i have tried to achieve the above layout.
http://www.bootply.com/ddBMU6HjwE

Why is my navbar breaking here?.

Comment: col-lg-12 col-ms-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 these classes set the width of the box to 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

http://www.bootply.com/9joMGFoxCU

...

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">  
    <div class="row">
      <div class="leftBox pull-left">Logo on Left</div>
      <div class="rightBox pull-right">Right Div</div>
       <div class="centerBox text-center">Center Stuff</div>
```

Very little custom CSS needed - just the height and width of the right .div, and the left-logo .div only if the logo size doesn't dictate that for you.

```
.rightBox{ height: 60px; width:260px;}
.leftBox { height: 60px; width:260px;}/* If logo img doesn't dictate this for you
.centerBox {}/* No custom CSS needed */
```

Answer (score 0):

Well for one, you have
`<div class="col-lg-12 col-ms-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 centerBox">`
which is displaying that div as 100% of the screen width in all cases, forcing your logo and rightbar to be displayed above and below it.  The idea of the columns is to have a dynamic method of resizing your webpage based on the device it's viewed on; you may want to do something like setting your middle content as `col-lg-8` and both the logo and rightbar as `col-lg-2`.

You may have to adjust this number for the other sizes, as a 300px image is going to take up more than 1/6th the page width on a phone then on a 1080p monitor.

EDIT: Got a version working: http://www.bootply.com/HVEW1iIWIB

Comment: Is my middle/center div 100% fluid width?

Comment: It does seem to be, doesn't it?

Answer (score -3):

Use this and if you want fix the width the with, please use position and width in css:

full code and demo at: http://www.bootply.com/cghQAenUTC

CSS:

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.rightBox{ float:right; height: 60px; border:1px dashed red; }
.leftBox { float:left; height: 60px;border:1px dashed red; }
.centerBox {height:60px; border:1px dashed red;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">    
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-2 leftBox">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
     </div>
   <div class="col-md-8 centerBox">hi</div>
     <div class="col-md-2 rightBox">right Div</div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```